# How to make override a ToString method of an WcF object?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, web

Basically I want to override a .ToString method of a WCF object on the server side.
How could this be accomplished?

Comment: You could override the method on the server side, but this overridden functionality will not show up for the clients (serialization is only for fields and properties, not methods). If you add some example code and show what you are wanted to see happen on the server and client sides we can better assist you.

Answer (score 8):

Classes generated from server-side WSDL are created as partial. You can do this:

```
public partial YourObject{

public override string ToString()
{
  //implementation
}
}
```

Comment: I don't quite follow you - where would i place that code?
At the server side I suppose?

Comment: @JohnMayer anywhere in your client. I usually make separate .cs files for this in the same folder where the service reference is.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the data contract on the server side (where you have your services)? If so what's stopping you to just override ToString() as you do for any other classes? However as pointed out by others it wouldn't be serialized (means it wouldn't show on the client side when you add a reference to that service).

You can do what Filip suggested above to get similar behaviour on the client side. Or you can just re-use the same dll (where you defined your data contracts) when you configure your service reference on the client.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override the ToString method of an auto generated class on the client, add a partial class with the same name in your client project and do something like this:

```
namespace yournamespace.yourserivcereference
{
 public partial class ClassYouWantToOverwrite
 {
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{somthing}";
    }
}
}
```

Dont forget to add your service reference to your namespace